# In Angular 9, can I adjust forkJoin so that results are processed as they are received?

Tags: angular, observable, fork-join

I'm using Angular 9.  I have the following component that displays a number of images

```
                    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let person of pageData; let i = index;" class="animated flipInX">

...
                          <img [src]="images[i]"
                            alt="" width="100%">
```

The images are loaded below using forkJoin.  This accomplishes the goal of being able to load my images in parallel ...

```
  let images$ = [];
  res.forEach(( componentarray, key ) => {
    images$.push( 
      this.authService.getImage(res[key].Id)
    );
  });
  const getImagesObservable = forkJoin(images$);
  getImagesObservable.subscribe(results => {
    results.forEach(( result, idx ) => {
      this.createTheImage(result, idx);
    })     
  });
});
```

The issue that I'm wondering about is that the images are only displayed when they are all loaded (all the calls complete).  I was curious if there is a way to load the images in parallel but also display the images as each call completes.

Comment: Isn't that just *not* `forkJoin`ing? The point to using that is when you want a collection of all of the results once all are complete; if you don't, don't use it. I.e. go back to what you had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64771410/3001761), it's not clear why that was a problem given the context in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `merge` instead of `forkJoin` to get what you want.

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

  const getImagesObservable = merge(...images$); // spread the array of observables
  getImagesObservable.subscribe(result => {
      this.createTheImage(result, idx);
  });
```